# Updated to Bootstrap 3.2.0 - nav header alignment became misaligned afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What the header looks like after the update:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSnPJ.png

Here is my jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SkLy7/1/

The fiddle includes external resources to CSS & JS.

Not sure how to fix. Any ideas?

HTML for my nav is:

```
<header>
    <div class="headerstrip navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="//rsatestamle.dminsite.com/" class="logo pull-left"><img src="http://cdnll.amleo.com/images/art/AMLLogo.png" art="ART" width="613" height="41" alt="AML Logo" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    <div id="TopNavigationControls">                        
                            <div id="topnav">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>

                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                            <li style="line-height: 20px;"><a class="AMLPhone" href="tel:1-800-543-8955" title="Phone">1-800-543-8955</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li style="line-height: 20px;"><a class="home" href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/" title="Home">Home</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li style="line-height: 20px;"><a class="myaccount" href="//rsatestamle.dminsite.com/Login.aspx" title="Login">Login</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li style="line-height: 20px;"><a class="shoppingcart" href="//rsatestamle.dminsite.com/cart.aspx" title="Cart">Cart</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <div class="HiringLink"><a class="NowHiring" href="/careers/a/66/" title="Now Hiring!">Now Hiring!</a></div>
                                    </ul>

                                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                                                                       
                                        <li><a href="/CategoryList.aspx">Categories</a></li>            
                                        <li><a href="/company-information/a/1/">About Us</a></li>        
                                        <li><a href="/catalogs.aspx">Request a Catalog</a></li>                                           
                                        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/leonard1885">Videos</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/CustomerService.aspx">Help</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/email-deals/a/25/">Email Deals</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/emaildeals/a/47_2/">Subscribe</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container White_BG">
        <div class="headerdetails hidden-print">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <form class="form-search top-search" action="Search.aspx" onsubmit="return validateSearch(this);" method="GET">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query yui-ac-input" name="ss" id="ss" placeholder="Search and find it fast" title="Search and find it fast" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search and find it fast'; }" onfocus="if ((this.value == 'Search and find it fast')||(this.value == 'Search and find it fast')) { this.value = ''; }" onkeypress="if ((this.value == 'Please enter a keyword or item #')||(this.value == 'Search and find it fast')) { this.value = ''; } else{ document.getElementsByName('ss')[0].style.color='black'; }" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="submit" title="Search" class="btn btn-orange SearchButton" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="pull-right">
                <div id="floating-cart-link">
                    <ul class="nav topcart pull-left">
                        <li id="floating-list" class="carticon cart">
                        <a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/cart.aspx" class="cart-tools-total" title="Shopping Cart"> Shopping Cart <span class="label label-orange font14" id="cartItemsNumber">0 item(s)</span> - <span id="itemsTotalCost">$0.00</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu topcartopen">
                        <li></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="cart-items-open" style="display: none;"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>


<div id="categorymenu">
    <nav class="subnav">
        <ul id="nav" class="nav-pills categorymenu">
            <li><a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/CategoryList.aspx" title="Categories">Categories <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></a>
                <div>

<ul id="nav">
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/am-leonard-brand-tools/c/10000000/">
            A.M. Leonard
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/arborist-supplies-ropes-saddles-spurs-tree-support/c/P13/">
            Arborist Supplies
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/container-production-pots-root-pouches-supports-weed-control-soilless-mix-wondersoil/c/P04/">
            Container Production
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/greenhouse-production-hydroponics-frost-protection-shade-fabric-pots-trays-baskets/c/P05/">
            Greenhouse Production
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/hand-tools/c/P01/">
            Hand Tools
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/field-production/c/P03/">
            Field Production
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/fertilizers-and-treatments/c/P15/">
            Fertilizers &amp; Treatments
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/herbicide-insecticide-fungicide/c/P16/">
            Herbicides, Insecticides, Fungicides
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/landscape-and-turf-management/c/P14/">
            Turf, Landscape Management
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/maintenance-supplies/c/P19/">
            Maintenance Supplies
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/marking-tagging/c/P12/">
            Marking &amp; Tagging
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/material-handling/c/P11/">
            Material Handling
        </a>
    </li></ul>
<ul id="nav">
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/measuring-surveying-testing/c/P02/">
            Measuring, Surveying, Testing
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/pest-control/c/P18/">
            Pest Control
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/power-equipment/c/P08/">
            Power Equipment
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/pruning/c/P10/">
            Pruning
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/safety/c/P07/">
            Safety
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/snow-and-winter/c/P20/">
            Snow &amp; Winter
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/sprayers%2c-spreaders-and-applicators/c/P17/">
            Sprayers, Spreaders and Applicators
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/watering-and-irrigation/c/P06/">
            Watering &amp; Irrigation
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/work-wear/c/P09/">
            Work Wear
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/clearance/c/123456789/">
            Clearance
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/made-in-the-u+s+a/c/USA_2012/">
            Made in the USA
        </a>
    </li></ul></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/brands.aspx" title="Brands">Brands <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></a>
                <div>
                    <ul><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/am-leonard-brand-tools/c/10000000/">A.M. Leonard</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/ames-true-temper/c/BR_1001_13/">Ames True Temper</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/ars/c/BR_1001_20/">ARS</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/bahco/c/BR_1001_24/">Bahco</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/corona/c/BR_1001_59/">Corona</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/felco/c/BR_1001_92/">Felco</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/florikan/c/BR_1001_452/">Florikan</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/ginegar-poly-film/c/BR_1001_530/">Ginegar Poly Film</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/haviland-plastic/c/BR_1001_438/">Haviland Plastic</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/king-of-spades/c/BR_1001_315/">King of Spades</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/permaloc/c/BR_1001_397/">Permaloc</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/plant-health-care/c/BR_1001_405/">Plant Health Care</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/silky/c/BR_1001_419/">Silky</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/solo/c/BR_1001_247/">Solo</a></li><li><a href="http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/treegator/c/BR_1001_284/">Treegator</a></li><li class="BrandsNavDropdown"><a href="//rsatestamle.dminsite.com/brands.aspx">All Brands...</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
<a href=" http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/new/c/P_NEW/" title="New Products">New</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=" http://rsatestamle.dminsite.com/clearance/c/123456789/" title="Clearance">Clearance <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icon-white"></i></a>
                <div>
                    <ul id="nav">
                        <li> 
                            <a href="http://iteminfo.amleo.com/poly/" target="_blank">Poly Remnant Sale</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/clearance/c/123456789/">Clearance Items</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
<a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/am-leonard-quick-how-to-guides/a/1001/" title="Our How-To Guides Are a Great Reference to Help You Work Smarter!">Guides</a>
            </li>
            <li>
<a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/CustomerService.aspx" title="Customer Service">Customer Care</a>
            </li>
            <li>
<a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/email-deals/a/25/" title="Email Deals">Email Deals</a>
            </li>
            <li>
<a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/catalogs.aspx" title="Catalogs">Catalog</a>
            </li>
            <li>
<a href=" //rsatestamle.dminsite.com/quickorder.aspx">Quick Order</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Your `.headerstrip` div has a `.row` and `.col-` classes, but not the next `.container`. Your `.row` should wrap the whole thing and use `.col- ` classes to set the widths.

Comment: So should .headerstrip be before or after .container? Then .row should be after container? Just making sure I understood.

Comment: Give me an hour and I'll test and post.

Comment: Working on it now. However...http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079

Answer (score 0):

Got you back on track. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiperific/WVJL2/3/).

**However** there is still much work to be done. Bootstrap 3 changed a lot of class terminology.

And you're using **a lot** of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags that will need to be converted to `<div>`s to get your drop-downs to work.

I tried to give lots of HTML comments to help you along.

---

**This will be a very time intensive project.**

You may decide to revert to Bootstrap 2 and stick with your original HTML file.

---

*But* with my help comes my big fat opinion. Ignore at will.

I'm hoping that this HTML was generated by some sort of UI like Wordpress, since it's a huge mess (hopefully that's not offensive).

It took me most of the time just fixing indentation so that the code could be readable.

If you're unfamiliar with HTML, CSS and Bootstrap, I would encourage you to spend some time on some tutorial sites getting more comfortable. I think you'll have trouble tweaking the rest of your updates without a good working knowledge of these three.